# Does this destop has voltage switch capability?

Tags: switch

In the past, I used to buy desktop in USA and there was a clear switch at the back of the cabinet to switch the input voltage from 220v to 110v and vice versa as mentioned [here](https://www.lifewire.com/power-supply-voltage-switch-2625973).
I am planning to buy this one:
https://www.costco.com/.product.100941399.html?EMID=B2C_2023_0322_DiningFocus
for my nephew in India.

Should I buy it? Upon checking with HP and Costco sales/customer service - there is no such switch in this desktop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many don't have switches these days, they're auto-switching - *but* you need to be able to read the info panel on the power supply to know for sure.

This is what it *must* say, 100-240V, ~50/60Hz

[image]

Only the info in the red box is significant. Random label from Google for a power supply, so no other info is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Yes @Tetsuhin - you are right. I can see this on the power supply.
It's Cooler Master PS-4601-1 power supply made for HP.
It can take 100V-240V